# Unable to add values to database by this simple method I created and getting an unknown error in android

Tags: java, android, database

So I am trying to add the user entered values which are both getting stored as String.
I have a getter and setter methods for values in my Classes named In_Debt and In_Credit.

I have a save button, on which a listener is running and when user click on the button, values from the text boxes are added to the database by calling the following function.

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()){
        case R.id.appCompatButtonSave:
            addToDataBase();
            break;
    }

}

private void addToDataBase() {
    addDebtsToDB.setNames(inDebtUserName.getText().toString().trim());
    addDebtsToDB.setAmount(inDebtUserAmount.getText().toString().trim());

    dbHelper.addInDebtDetails(addDebtsToDB);

    Snackbar.make(nestedScrollView, "Your Debts Are Remembered", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    emptyInputEditText();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Intent goingBack = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityHome.class);
    startActivity(goingBack);
}
```

I have tried debuggin but all that happens is that it jumps to Looper.class, I have no idea what that is and why this is happening. 
My login and register data are getting verified and added to the database in other Activities respectively but I have done similar stuff here also but I am not able to understand why is this not working.

Comment: can you post the complete log here.

Comment: Ok, just a minute

Comment: I have set the break-point at "private void addToDataBase()"
[debug image](https://s26.postimg.org/ud1jk73nt/debug_log.png)

[| another debug image](https://s26.postimg.org/3qp2v7zgp/debug_log_2.png)

@gautham

Comment: Its throwing ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller Exception.bcz its not ablet o access the view of inDebtUserName and inDebtUserAmount in addToDataBase()

Answer (score 0):

these below are the basic steps to understand the android database

1. create Contact.java class

   package com.example.sqlite;
   public class Contact {
   int _id;
   String _name;
   String _phone_number;
    public Contact(){   }
   public Contact(int id, String name, String _phone_number){
       this._id = id;
       this._name = name;
       this._phone_number = _phone_number;
   }

   public Contact(String name, String _phone_number){
       this._name = name;
       this._phone_number = _phone_number;
   }
   public int getID(){
       return this._id;
   }

   public void setID(int id){
       this._id = id;
   }

   public String getName(){
       return this._name;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       this._name = name;
   }

   public String getPhoneNumber(){
       return this._phone_number;
   }

   public void setPhoneNumber(String phone_number){
       this._phone_number = phone_number;
   }
   }
2. Now, let's create the database handler class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper class and provides the implementation of its methods.

   package com.example.sqlite;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";
     private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_PH_NO = "phone_number";

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {  
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);  
    //3rd argument to be passed is CursorFactory instance  
}  

// Creating Tables  
@Override  
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("  
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"  
            + KEY_PH_NO + " TEXT" + ")";  
    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);  
}  

// Upgrading database  
@Override  
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {  
    // Drop older table if existed  
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);  

    // Create tables again  
    onCreate(db);  
}  

 // code to add the new contact  
 void addContact(Contact contact) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name  
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone  

    // Inserting Row  
    db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);  
    //2nd argument is String containing nullColumnHack  
    db.close(); // Closing database connection  
}  

// code to get the single contact  
Contact getContact(int id) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();  

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,  
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);  
    if (cursor != null)  
        cursor.moveToFirst();  

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),  
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));  
    // return contact  
    return contact;  
}  

// code to get all contacts in a list view  
public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {  
    List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();  
    // Select All Query  
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;  

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);  

    // looping through all rows and adding to list  
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {  
        do {  
            Contact contact = new Contact();  
            contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));  
            contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));  
            contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));  
            // Adding contact to list  
            contactList.add(contact);  
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());  
    }  

    // return contact list  
    return contactList;  
}  

// code to update the single contact  
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
    values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());  
    values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());  

    // updating row  
    return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });  
}  

// Deleting single contact  
public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();  
    db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",  
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });  
    db.close();  
}  

// Getting contacts Count  
public int getContactsCount() {  
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;  
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();  
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);  
    cursor.close();  

    // return count  
    return cursor.getCount();  
}
```

}

3. Now in your activity

   package com.example.sqlite;

import java.util.List;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override  
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);  

     // Inserting Contacts  
    Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");  
    db.addContact(new Contact("Ravi", "9100000000"));  
    db.addContact(new Contact("Srinivas", "9199999999"));  
    db.addContact(new Contact("Tommy", "9522222222"));  
    db.addContact(new Contact("Karthik", "9533333333"));  

    // Reading all contacts  
    Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");  
    List<Contact> contacts = db.getAllContacts();         

    for (Contact cn : contacts) {  
     String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() + " ,Phone: " +   
        cn.getPhoneNumber();  
    // Writing Contacts to log  
    Log.d("Name: ", log);  
}  
}  

@Override  
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {  
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.  
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);  
    return true;  
}
```

}

4. Please add require permission in manifest file

Comment: I know how android database works, and my login and register are working great with the same database which is used to do this task.

But your answer does not have the required solution. Still thanks.

Comment: If I have not added permissions then how does the login and register be working. I think you just saw the heading and posted answer without reading the complete question.